# Find all elements $x \in \mathbb{Z}_{96}$ such that $\left<x\right>=\left<12\right>$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Find all elements $x \in \mathbb{Z}_{96}$ such that $\left<x\right>=\left<12\right>$.

I know the answer of this question, the answer is $\left<12,36,60,84\right>$.

However, I am confused that why the answer is not $\left<12,24,36,48,60,72,84\right>$. Can anyone help me?

Comment: First, the answer should be $\{12,36,60,84\}$ (note the use of $\{\}$, not $\langle \rangle$). 
 Have you tried computing $\langle 24\rangle$?

Comment: Why don't you try to see what happens?  $<24> = \{24,48,72, 0\}$ well that *isn't* $<12>$.  And $<48>=\{48,0\}$ and $<72>=\{72, 48, 24,0\}$.  So what do you thing those multiples of 12 have that the other multiples of $12$ don't.

Answer (score 4):

Note that $\left<24\right> = \{0, 24, 48, 72\}$ since $72+24 = 96 \equiv 0 \pmod{96}$, but $\left<12\right> = \{0, 12, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84\}$.

The reason why this is so is since $\gcd(12,96) = \gcd(36,96) = \gcd(60,96) = \gcd(84,96) = 12$ but $\gcd(24,96) = 24$...

Comment: @rayray218 I don't think you need to eliminate it. You just need to make sure $x \in \left<12\right>$ and $12 \in \left<x\right>$, which is forced by that $\gcd(x,96) = 12$ condition

Answer (score 2):

For $⟨x⟩$ to be equal to $⟨12⟩$, $12$ needs to be an element of $⟨x⟩$ and $x$ needs to be an element of $⟨12⟩$. Clearly $24, 48$ and $72$ are elements of $⟨12⟩$ but $12$ is not an element of $⟨x⟩$ in any of these cases.

For $12$ to be an element of $⟨x⟩$, we need $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{96}$ such that $nx \equiv12 \ (\text{mod} \ 96).$

Take $24$ as an example. We find the congruence $24n \equiv 12 \ (\text{mod} \ 96) $ is not solvable as $\gcd(24, 96) = 24$ and $24$ doesn't divide $12$, therefore $12 \notin ⟨24⟩$. This is the same for $48$ and $72$. In the other cases, the congruence is solvable, so $12 \in ⟨x⟩$.

Comment: +1 another good way to look at it. Can you perhaps elaborate why $12 \in \left<36\right>$ but $12 \not \in \left<24\right>$?

Comment: @gt6989b thanks! I think you put that very well in your own answer but I've tried to add some explanation to mine.

Answer (score 0):

The subgroup $\langle12\rangle$ is generated by $12a$ if and only if $a$ is coprime to $\frac{96}{12}=8$, i.e. odd. Hence, $12=12 \cdot 1$, $36=12 \cdot 3$, $60=12 \cdot 5$, and $84=12 \cdot 7$ are generators, but $24=12 \cdot 2$, $48=12 \cdot 4$, and $72=12 \cdot 6$ are not.

Answer (score 0):

$\gcd(12,96) = \gcd(36,96)= \gcd(60,96)=\gcd(84)=12$.

$\gcd(24,96) = \gcd(72,96)=24 \ne 12$

And $\gcd(48,96) = 48\ne 12$.

Can you see why that would make a difference?

(Note every element of $<a>\subset \mathbb Z_{m}$ will be a multiple of $\gcd(a,m)$.  So $<24>$ will only contain multiples of $24$ and will not contain any multiples of $12$ that are *not* multiples of $24$.)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\: (x)\!=\!(12)$ in $\Bbb Z_{96}\!\!\iff\! (x,96)\!=\!(12)\!\! $ $ \iff\!\! ({\large \frac{x}{12}},8)\! =\! 1\!\! \iff\!\! {\large \frac{x}{12}} \equiv 1,3,5,7 \pmod{\!8}$